# Do I have to study the correlation between ordinal and nominal variables together?

Tags: regression, logistic, categorical-data

I have a data frame made up of categorical and ordinal variables, I want to make a multiple binary logistic regression model.

The steps that I am going to carry out are:
See if the variables meet the multicollinearity condition: on the one hand I see the correlation between the ordinal variables with the Spearman correlation matrix and on the other hand I see the relationship between the nominal variables with the VIF method.

- Do I then have to make a correlation between nominals and ordinals if I am going to put them all together in the same model?

Comment: Multicollinearity usually is one of the last things you want to check.   Is there any problem or concern with fitting the model you have planned to use?

Comment: All I want is to make sure that my variables are not correlated with each other in order to apply logistic regression.

Comment: But that's not a requirement for logistic regression -- or indeed, for almost any form of regression.

Comment: See [this list of posts about logistic regression and multicolinearity](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=multicolinearity++logistic+regression++answers%3A1)